# Youtube Player API Difference (Chromeless vs IFrame) - Which is better?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, chromeless

So I have scoured the web on information on how to embed the Youtube players but actual detailed tutorials seem extremely sparse or completely non existent. In addition, although there is documentation found on the google site
it seems to be somewhat confusing for a novice on how to implement either which leads me to my question. It seems that there are two players, the ***IFrame*** player and the ***Chromeless*** player which uses an swf embed. I have gone ahead and provided examples of both:

*IFrame Player*(using angular): http://plnkr.co/edit/H5VnlPhOaa2n6ZsfSj5p?p=preview

*Chromeless Player*: http://plnkr.co/edit/Epz9uXDZ1uIiV4lgB0vw?p=preview

My question is, what is the difference? What is the advantage of using one over the other? Does one have more backwards compatibility with browsers? Mobile Support? The Chromeless player seems to require less code to run as most of the code runs out of the box from the included "swfobject.js".In addition it seems that the chromeless player does not work on iOS devices due to the flash requirement. Is this correct?

*Addendum*: You can see the iframe and chromeless player are mostly the same besides the fact that you can click on the iframe youtube player to pause it while the chromeless player can only be controlled from the play/pause controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One big benefit to using iFrames with Youtube is that it is basically a new window with a call back to youtube... and guess what?  Youtube will interpret what browser and platform the request is coming from and populate the appropriate content BUT iFrame can be slow loading on older browsers and on mobile devices where object/embed would not. Parameter settings (to tune the user experience on your site) is roughly the same. We all know SWF files won't work on iOS so you might need to factor that into your development for your userbase.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Player API is an older API that was used to embed YouTube videos on a website. (Chromeless API)

YouTube IFrame Player API is the newer API that replaced the YouTube Player API. It allows us to embed a YouTube video player on your website and control the player using JavaScript.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).